# C++ Function Returning Vector Combining Two Vector Parameters

Tags: function, vector, cout

Amateur C++ Student
Assignment is to create a function that takes two vectors of strings and returns a third vector that combines the contents of the first two in alternating form, with any leftover at the end.
It compiles and runs, but asks for input before displaying contents, one line at a time. Please nothing fancy, I would just like to know where I messed up. Thank you!

```
vector<string> shuffle(vector<string> L1, vector<string> L2);

int main() {

    string s;
    vector<string> L1;
    vector<string> L2;

    cout << "Enter words for the first list\n";
    while (cin >> s && s != "END") {
        L1.push_back(s);
    }

    cout << "Enter words for the second list\n";
    while (cin >> s && s != "END") {
        L2.push_back(s);
    }   

    shuffle(L1, L2);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < L3.size(); k++) {
    cout << L3[k] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

vector<string> shuffle(vector<string> L1, vector<string> L2) {  
    vector<string> L3;
    string s;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < L1.size() && i < L2.size(); i++) {
        if (i < L1.size()) {
            cout << L1[i] << " ";
            cin >> s;
            L3.push_back(s);
        }   
        if (i < L2.size()) {
            cout << L2[i] << " ";
            cin >> s;
            L3.push_back(s);
        }
    }       

    if (L1.size() > L2.size()) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < (L1.size()-L2.size()); j++) {
            cout << L1[j+L2.size()] << " ";
            cin >> s;
            L3.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    if (L2.size() > L1.size()) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < (L2.size()-L1.size()); j++) {
            cout << L2[j+L1.size()] << " ";
            cin >> s;
            L3.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    return L3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `shuffle` asks for input since you call `cin >> s` from it. `shuffle` doesn't really operate with two string vectors passed as arguments. Actually, it ignores values of strings passed to it, forming L3 of newly entered strings.

Comment: So the way my function is defined is okay, i just need to correct the parameters?

Comment: It depends on what you want your function to do. As I can see, it is supposed to merge two vectors `L1` and `L2` somehow, but instead it asks user for input and forms a new vector using user enetered values, and the contents of `L1` and `L2` are left unused. I'd say you have to change your function body rather than "parameters".